# MySQL databases need server

Tags: mysql

I have been using My SQL databases for a few months now. And the databases are stored locally. So while using these databases in Python, R, I have to make a database connection. Is there anyway I can use MySQL databases without such connection, like in we use .db files in sqlite3?

Comment: No.  And what has this to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: Oh. I posted this using the Stack Exchange application. Didn't know it got posted in here.